# Zero solution of PDE of mixed-type.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the problem of infinitesimal surface bending. Now my step is to show that this PDE of mixed type has only zero solution($h \in C^{k\geqslant2}$, $a > 0$) So my academic advisor told me that I need to somehow simplify this equation, preserving the fact, that $h(u,v) = o(\frac{1}{u^2+v^2})$ at $\infty$ And I have no idea how can I do this. If someone has got any idea. Because I even don't know what form should be equation to conclude that it's only solutions is trivial: $\bigg(-2a+(u^2+v^2)^2h_{vv}-2 u (u^2 + v^2)h_{u}+2v(u^2 + v^2)h_{v}\bigg)\xi_{uu}+\\+ \bigg(-2a+(u^2+v^2)^2h_{uu}+2u(u^2+v^2)h_{u}-2v(u^2+v^2)h_{v}\bigg)\xi_{vv}+\\+\bigg(-2(u^2+v^2)^2h_{uv}-4v(u^2+v^2)h_{u}-4 u(u^2+v^2)h_{v}\bigg)\xi_{uv}+\\+\bigg(-2u(u^2+v^2)h_{uu}+2u(u^2+v^2)h_{vv}-4v(u^2+v^2)h_{uv}-8
(u^2+v^2)h_{u}\bigg)\xi_u+\\+\bigg(2v(u^2+v^2)h_{uu}-2v(u^2+v^2)h_{vv}-4u(u^2+v^2)h_{uv}-8(u^2+ v^2)h_{v}\bigg)\xi_{v}=0$ $$\begin{cases}
\left.\xi\right\vert_{\infty} = 0 \\
\left.d\xi\right\vert_{\infty} = 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: What is $\xi$? Is it an unkown function? One approach might be to find some change of variables to make the terms in parentheses more manageable. If $\xi$ is a known function, then you might be able to use properties of its second derivatives to determine if the equation is elliptic/hyperbolic/parabolic. Without knowing that, you really can't even start applying any analysis

Comment: $\xi$ is vertical component of vector field of  infinitesimal bending. And it is an unknown function.

Comment: 2 unknown functions in a single equation is not a well-posed system. There is certainly no uniqueness of any functions satisfying this equation

Comment: The function $h$ is known for each surface. I mean the surface was of the form : $f(x,y)=1-a(x^2+y^2)+h(x,y)$ where $h=o(x^2+^2)$ whenever $x^2+y^2 \to 0$ so after that I did a stereo graphic projection

Comment: Oh I see. I thought that $h$ was an unknown. My initial thought is that you still want to determine if the equation is elliptic/hyperbolic/etc. and to do that globally you will need global information on the derivatives of $h$. If you denote the first 3 terms groups in parentheses as $A$, $C$, and $B$, then the sign of $B^2-4AC$ will determine the type of equation. Obviously the sign of the derivatives of $h$ will influence this heavily